# How to center multiple divs within a section?

Tags: html, css

I know there is an existing question none of the solutions seem to work for me and it's a question posted in 2014.

Here's the code I have:

```
 <section id="team-block">
  <div class="team-block-centered">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 member-1">
      <div class="team-member">
        <img
          src="http://lvsmiledesigners.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/dr-tongsiri.jpg"
          data-original="http://lvsmiledesigners.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/dr-tongsiri.jpg"
          alt=""
          class="lazy"
          style="display: block;"
        />
        <div class="inner">
          <h4 class="name">Dr. Amy Tongsiri</h4>
          <p class="position">
            <small>Clinical Director</small>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="hover">
          <div class="description">
            <p>
              Dr. Amy Tongsiri has joined Smile Designers of Las Vegas in 2017.
              She has a joyous energy vibrating the room as she enters. Almost
              permanently smiling, she exudes positivity and can easily relaxed
              and soothe a nervous patient. The desire to pursue a career in
              dentistry came young for Dr. Tongsiri, during the course of her
              own dental health. "I originally wanted to do orthodontics, when I
              had braces,” she says, flashing the resulting perfect smile. “But
              eventually, I found General Dentistry to be more exciting because
              you are challenged by being able to cover everything."
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="read-more">
            <a href="/new/dr-amy-tongsiri/" class="button white outline"
              >Read more <span class="nc-icon-glyph arrows-1_bold-right"></span
            ></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--.hover-->
      </div>
      <!--.team-member-->
    </div>
    <!--.col-lg-3-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 member-2">
    <div class="team-member">
      <img
        src="http://lvsmiledesigners.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Dr-Dominique-Dela-Cruz.jpg"
        data-original="http://lvsmiledesigners.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Dr-Dominique-Dela-Cruz.jpg"
        alt=""
        class="lazy"
        style="display: block;"
      />
      <div class="inner">
        <h4 class="name">Dr. Dominique Dela Cruz</h4>
        <p class="position">
          <small>Lead Dentist</small>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="hover">
        <div class="description">
          <p>
            Providing comprehensive dental care that is tailored to each and
            every patient’s needs is Dr. Dominique Dela Cruz’s goal when it
            comes to treating patients. She strives to provide dental care in a
            comfortable environment while using the most innovative and advanced
            technology. Dr. Dela Cruz grew up in Las Vegas, NV. On her spare
            time, she likes to stay outdoors as much as possible. She loves to
            hike, travel, kayak and snowboard. She also likes to read books and
            watch movies with her dogs. Like most of her patients, Dr. Dela Cruz
            has a sweet tooth and enjoys eating candy, chocolate and other
            pastries.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a href="/new/dr-jorge-jimenez-marquez/" class="button white outline"
            >Read more <span class="nc-icon-glyph arrows-1_bold-right"></span
          ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--.hover-->
    </div>
    <!--.team-member-->
  </div>
  <!--.col-lg-3-->
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 member-3">
    <div class="team-member">
      <img
        src="http://lvsmiledesigners.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/karla.jpg"
        data-original="http://lvsmiledesigners.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/karla.jpg"
        alt=""
        class="lazy"
        style="display: block;"
      />
      <div class="inner">
        <h4 class="name">Karla Brown</h4>
        <p class="position">
          <small>Office Manager</small>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="hover">
        <div class="description">
          <p>
            Delivering outstanding customer service has always been an essential
            part of a day’s work for Karla. As Smile Designers of Las Vegas
            Office Manager, she is responsible for all office procedures, and
            uses her organizational skills to ensure smooth operations in a busy
            work environment.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a href="/new/nancy-gutierrez/" class="button white outline"
            >Read more <span class="nc-icon-glyph arrows-1_bold-right"></span
          ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--.hover-->
    </div>
    <!--.team-member-->
  </div>
  <!--.col-lg-3-->
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 member-4">
    <div class="team-member">
      <img
        src="http://lvsmiledesigners.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/nancy.jpg"
        data-original="http://lvsmiledesigners.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/nancy.jpg"
        alt=""
        class="lazy"
        style="display: block;"
      />
      <div class="inner">
        <h4 class="name">Nancy Gutierrez</h4>
        <p class="position">
          <small>Lead Back Office Assistant</small>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="hover">
        <div class="description">
          <p>
            As Smile Designers of Las Vegas lead dental assistant she says her
            coworkers and easy-going patients make it a pleasure to go to work
            every day. She loves been a part in patients journeys to a better
            and healthier oral health.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a href="/new/karla-brown/" class="button white outline"
            >Read more <span class="nc-icon-glyph arrows-1_bold-right"></span
          ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--.hover-->
    </div>
    <!--.team-member-->
  </div>
  <!--.col-lg-3-->
</section>
```

Here's the live site: http://lvsmiledesigners.com/new/

The section is under the "Our team can help you!" header.  The concern I have is Dr. Amy's div.  I'm not sure why Dr. Amy's image is narrower in width than the other images.

Comment: Please, ident your code to make it readable for users that want to help you. 
Also, try to provide a [mcve] without the need to navigate to another site

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: The image is fine. It is just short. Give it fixed height and an auto width for all the images in the row.

Comment: if possible, you could opt to use a grid container  to showcase your images, it would give you a better control over what happens with the image and sizing. check the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ujodrxf/), and also check the [CSS tricks tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). It might also be good to limit based on height instead of width to make your images more uniform. Check the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Update]:** You should wrap all the doctors column with `.team-block-centered` to positioning them center. In your demo live site - you only wrap Dr. Amy `div`.

See your code, all the element with `col-lg-3` class aren't siblings, instead Dr. Amy div element nested in `.team-block-centered` element. And thats the main reason. If you remove parent wrapper with class `.team-block-centered`, everything will be fine.

**[Previous]:**
`.team-block-centered` parent wrapper class has width 900px. And `col-lg-3` class take the width of 20%(234px in this case).

The problem is you have 4 column width of `20% * 4 = 80%(234 * 4 = 936px)`, which is greater than parent wrapper width.

Give `.team-block-centered` class `width: 100%` , and then center it.

Comment: Realized I had only one div nested inside the .team-blocked-centered div.  Had to move the ending </div> so that all the divs were contained, then I resized the image.

Answer (score 0):

In other words image is very short in width = 173px original, it should more than 204px.